# How to add transparent content over background image (entered in css) for home page only

Tags: css, wordpress

In Genesis framework, I can't figure out how to add content directly over background image (without the white body text box). The website is www.vacounseling.com. Please help!

CSS code:

```
body.home { background-image: url("https://www.vacounseling.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2016/08/DSCN4252-6.jpg");}
body {background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-attachment: scroll; 
color:#222;
margin:0;
padding:0;  
opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: have you tried setting: background-color: transparent or #0000

Comment: After looking at the site you attached i believe the below edit will give you the outcome you want 

.content .entry {
    background-color: #0000;
}

Comment: Yes, both of these did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then as Dylan mentioned above you want to add the CSS of

```
.content .entry {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you!

Comment: @John Accept this as the answer so the question is closed :)